# Всегда ли слово "конституция" пишется с большой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Что-то меня заклинило. Слово "конституция" всегда пишется с большой буквы или только тогда, когда речь идет о законе собственной страны? А если, скажем, в России говорят о конституции Украины?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово “конституция”- не имя собственное, оно  обозначает “устройство”, то есть то, как устраивается, строится государство. В нашей стране много законов, но главным законом нашего государства является Конституция. В знак уважения к основному закону страны слово “Конституция” пишется с заглавной буквы.

http://www.bibliotekar.ru/biznes-58/24.htm
В названиях актов высших органов государственной власти и управления Российской Федерации прописные буквы употребляются следующим образом:
Конституция (Основной Закон) Российской Федерации;
Конституция (но: конституции республик). Когда говорится о конституциях других государств,слово пишется со строчной буквы.

Answer (score 0):

[Конституция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0) еще может означать состояние человеческого организма в физическом плане. В этом случае естественно, что это слово пишется со строчной буквы.
В случае речи об основном законе - см. ответ [@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0).